# C++ open source library for formatted output of a table

Tags: c++, number-formatting

Is there any open source C++ library for table formatting?

Something that allows me to write

```
Table t;// Table is a class provided by the library
t.column(2);
t.name(0,"x");
t.name(1,"x^2");
t.type("x",Table::Integer);
t.type("x^2",Table::Integer);
t.width("x",1);
t.width("x^2",2);
for( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
 t.set("x",i);
 t.set("x^2",i*i);
}
std::cout << t;
```

and get this textual output

```
0  0
1  1
2  4
3  9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
```

It must be capable to manage also floating point numbers, not just integers.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-built libraries I know of for this kind of thing are mostly GUI oriented, so the data is displayed in spreadsheet-like cells instead of just as text.

Looking at your idea of how to use the library, it strikes me as fitting C++ rather poorly though. Keep in mind that C++ uses static typing, where your `t.type("x", Table::Integer)` tends to imply dynamic typing (i.e., specifying the type of that column at run time instead of compile time).

Personally, I'd probably think in terms of a formatting object that stored formatting information for *one* object. You'd then have a "column" with a formatting object and vector of associated data. Finally, you'd have a "table" with an arbitrary number of columns. Most of this (especially the types) would be specified as template arguments, so you might have something like:

```
class format { 
    int w, p;
public:
    format(int width = 0, int precision = 0) : w(width), precision(p) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, format const &f) { 
        return os << std::setw(f.w) << std::setprecision(f.p);
    }
};

template <class T, class container = std::vector<T> >
class Column {
    format f;
    std::string label;
    container data;
public:
    Column(std::string const &l, format const &fmt) : f(fmt), label(l) {}
    void push_back(T const &d) { data.push_back(d); }
};

format fmt1(1);
format fmt2(2);

Column<int> c1("x", fmt1);
Column<int> c2("x^2", fmt2);

table<2> my_table(c1, c2);
```

I'd *probably* then design the table to act roughly like a `vector<tuple<values> >`, so to add the values, you'd do something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    my_table.push_back(make_tuple(i, i*i));
```

The method you've used (based on the name of the column instead of the position) could probably be done, but the obvious way (a `map<std::string, value>`) would only work if all the columns had the same type. To support multiple column types, you could do something like `map<std::string, boost::any>`, but I'd stay away from that if at all reasonable.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. I think I'll try to code something based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any libraries.
But you can overload the `<<` operator for your class `Table` and you can achieve the same.

EDIT:
To clarify on your comment of `Table` being an Library class, It does not affect overloading the `<<` because it is overloaded as an `non-member` free function.

Code Example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Table& obj) 
{ 
  // write obj to stream in whichever way you like
  return os;
}
```

Comment: Table is supposed to be a class supplyed from the library. I will clarify the question.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: `<<` is usually overloaded as an non-member function,So it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: maybe I did not explain enough my problem. I just have the numbers i and i^2 and the library I am looking for should give me a class like Table.